# Recover files ex-internal, soon to be external Windows 7 primary hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery

I have a broken Laptop with Windows 7 on it. The laptop needs a new motherboard and needs to be sent to the manufacturer for a while. Owner of the laptop needs her files while it will be gone.

So I've decided to get one of those internal hard drive enclosures (Which allow you to turn your internal hard drive into a USB or eSATA external hard drive), take the internal HD out and stick in in the enclosure.

My question is: will I be able to access all files on the hard drive no problem? Doesn't Windows 7 encrypt the user's folders? I'm not talking about any bitlocker encryption or bios HDD password, I know none of that is used on the laptop. Its a normal laptop with standard windows 7 home configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can have access to all your files. If you still have issues accessing them use a linux live cd (like Ubuntu) to boot your system with your HDD and you will be able to access them !

Answer (score 2):

If the user has a password on their Windows 7 login it will probably ask you for it when you try to go into the C:\Users[name] folder. You could do what Chakib suggested and use a Ubuntu Live CD/Live USB to ignore the permissions and copy the files.